# How come the Euclidian distance for n-space involves only squares?

Tags: geometry, general-topology

I'm just beginning to learn topology, and there's something that I realize has been nagging at me since roughly the eight grade.

Why does the Euclidean distance in N-dimensional space involve a bunch of squaring and square-rooting?

I understand it, mind you.

1. In 1-space the "distance" is $\sqrt{\Delta x^2}$ is which is just $\Delta x$.
2. In two-space, you're doing the Pythagorean theorem.
3. In 3-space, I visualize it like this: you want to find the distance $\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z$ so you:

   - let $a = \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$, $a$ is the distance along the $x, y$ plane
   - the total distance is $\sqrt{a^2 + \Delta z^2}$
   - the above expands to $\sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2}$

To generalize, faced with $n$ dimensions, you pick two, find the distance along those two dimensions, plop a point down there, and repeat (until you have only one dimension left, at which point you're done.)

However, I don't understand *why* distance in n-space requires repeated squaring. Shouldn't there be a distance formula that requires cubing and the cube-root in three-space, or quading (is that a thing) and quad-roots in four-space, and so on? Just in the interest of symmetry, it seems weird that squares get special treatment.

I know this is a very philosophical question, but is there a way to find Euclidean distances in n-space that involves taking the nth power and nth root instead of repeatedly projecting down a dimension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are other metrics than the Euclidean one.  In particular, you can define the "$\ell^p$ norm" for any $p \ge 1$, where the distance from $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ to $(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)$ is $(|x_1 - y_1|^p + |x_2 - y_2|^p + \ldots + |x_n - y_n|^p)^{1/p}$.  What is special about the Euclidean metric is that it allows rotations through arbitrary angles.

Comment: Cool! Are there any uses to such alternative definitions? Also, what do you mean by saying that one allows rotation while the other does not? How can a distance metric prevent rotation?

Comment: What Robert means is that the Euclidean distance of two points will be the same before and after you rotate them. This is not necessarily the case for other metrics.

Answer (score 5):

An explanation with some algebraic flavor is through linear transformations and [inner products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space); these inner products $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ are fundamental objects for vector spaces as they can quantitatively measure linear independence through bilinearity. On the assumption of a basis for our space we can define the inner product to be the dot product $x\cdot y=\sum_ix_iy_i$; this is the unique inner product for which $\langle e_i,e_i\rangle=1$ for each basis vector $e_i$. However, being linear in both arguments means that scalar multiplication gives $\langle \lambda v,\lambda v\rangle=\lambda^2\langle v,v\rangle$. In order to force this to be scalar multiplicative we need to set $\|v\|=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$, so that $\|\lambda v\| = |\lambda|\,\|v\|$.

So ultimately, this way of explanation boils down to: a translation-invariant metric is equivalent to having a norm on the space, and the Euclidean norm will be a special case of "measuring" the linear independence of a vector with itself, in the sense of an inner product, so the presence of the distinguished power/root of two is because one and one (a vector and its copy) make two.